# jquery slide down function inside a loop

Tags: php, jquery

i have a jquery function which takes place inside a php loop but i am unable to make it work

**Jquery.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#comment_button").click(function(){
        $("#comment_type_area").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

**index.php**

```
....

    echo"<div id='comment_button'>
                Comment
            </div>
            <div id='comment_type_area'>
                <textarea class='commnt' post_id='<?php $shared_id2; ?>' id='text_comment' placeholder='Write a Comment'></textarea><br>
                <button id='post_button' type='button'>Post</button> 
            </div>";
```

**Output**

[image]

As you can see i am unable to slide down the rest of the comment div Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ids, ids have to be unique per document.

Try to use classes like:

```
$(".comment_button").click(function(){
   $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Comment: Wow dude this totally worked cant believe it was this simple
may i know why it worked ?? i don't seem to understand

Comment: You said that your jquery code is within a loop. That means you have all your comments with the same id. Ids have to be unique. Classes can be multiple per page. When you click on one of those buttons you can use $(this) which is the actuall element you clicked on.